# Summing range of values in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose I have a table as this:

```
      A    B

1    12   4.5
2    22   1.7
3    44   3.4
4    17   2.2
5    11   1.9
6    23   2.7
```

How do I write a command to sum up values of B given a certain range of A? For example, the sum of B values of A range 11-20 would be 4.5 + 2.2 + 1.9 = 8.6 I only want to sum the values for column B which fit into that range of A.

I'm assuming you need a statement which checks if the value of A fits into the range, then mapping that corresponding row to the value of B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try SUMIFS if you have Excel 2007 or later

`=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">=11",A:A,"<=20")`

look like the answer for that is actually 8.6

Answer (score 0):

The following formula should do the job. It a assumes that the data range is A1:B6, 11 in is B8 and 20 is in B9:

```
  =SUM((A1:A6>=B8)*(A1:A6<=B9)*(B1:B6))
```

As an array formula, it needs to be entered with the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination.